# Using IN() within a CASE statement in Oracle APEX SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to use the `IN()` function within a `CASE` statement for a generated column?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE  "table1" 
   ("column1" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "column2" VARCHAR2(30) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE "column1"
                                                WHEN IN('val1', 'val2') THEN 'result1'
                                                                        ELSE 'result2'
                                                END) VIRTUAL NOT NULL ENABLE
   )
```

When I try to execute this, I'm getting `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Obvious workaround is to use `WHEN 'val1' THEN x WHEN 'val2' THEN y`
But the actual list of values I'm working with is huge (60+), and many of them have the same result, so I'm trying to condense, and make the code more readable, and simpler to compile.

Comment: Yeah, CASE has a couple of slight variations, depending on what your expression is. If you were comparing discrete values, that format would have been OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I guess you just missed column name after case when its not `case "column" when in..` but below

```
   Select case when "column1" in (   
   'value1', 'value2' then.. End) from table
```